# How to find and display all instances of a pattern in a SQL Server string?

Tags: sql-server, substring, udf, patindex

So I am trying to write a UDF that will pull specific data from a string.

```
  'random text here Task 1234 blah blah more text task 4567'
```

I want to extract 'Task 1234 and task 4567' and have them display like such

```
  'Task 1234, task 4567'
```

Here's what I got so far, but only seem to be able to get either the first task or the second but not both.

```
Alter Function [dbo].[fn_GetTask](@strText VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS varchar(1000)
AS
BEGIN
  while patindex('%Task%', @strText) > 0

BEGIN
    SET @strText = substring(@strText, (CHARINDEX(substring(@strText, Patindex('%Task%', @strText) +4, 5), @strText, 5)),5)
    end
RETURN @strText

END
```

It's been a very long day. I feel like I'm missing something really basic here.

Comment: will the string always have task followed by 4 digits?and is there a limit on how many instances of task can the string have?

Comment: no limit on the number of tasks theoretically, but usually < 10.  and yes will always be 4 digits, but may not always be a space, could be a task: or task- etc... but if I could even grab the ones with the space I'd be happy

Comment: you are overwriting the original string with your first instance of the task you need an additional string to track the remaining portion of the string or simply track the index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ALTER Function [dbo].[fn_GetTask](@strText VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS varchar(1000)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @ReturnString VARCHAR(1000) = ''

    WHILE PATINDEX('%Task%', @strText) > 0

    BEGIN

       DECLARE @FoundString VARCHAR(1000) = SUBSTRING(@strText,PATINDEX('%Task%',@strText),9)

       IF (LEN(@ReturnString) > 0)
       BEGIN
          SET @ReturnString += ', '
       END

       SET @ReturnString += @FoundString

       SET @strText = RIGHT(@strText,LEN(@strText) - PATINDEX('%' + @FoundString + '%',@StrText))
    END

    RETURN @ReturnString

END
```

As I had mentioned during your while loop you where over writing your string you where searching through with your results string.  you didn't have a mechanism to trim that original string or track your progress here is one way to do it, I used additional variables just so I didn't have to nest the same statement a couple of times.

Comment: I'm sure all the answers are correct but I read Matt's comment about writing over my variable and that was the obvious oversight on my part.  Even when I thought I was accounting for it.

Answer (score 3):

If you need more SET-based solution, you can search as follows:

```
DECLARE @pattern nvarchar(MAX) = N'%task [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%';
DECLARE @input nvarchar(MAX) = N'random text here Task 1212 blah blah more text task 4567';
WITH Src AS
(
    SELECT
        SUBSTRING(@input, PATINDEX(@pattern, @input), 9) Val,
        STUFF(@input, 1, PATINDEX(@pattern, @input)+9, '') Txt
        WHERE PATINDEX(@pattern, @input)>0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        SUBSTRING(Txt, PATINDEX(@pattern, Txt), 9),
        STUFF(Txt, 1, PATINDEX(@pattern, Txt)+9, '')
    FROM Src
    WHERE PATINDEX(@pattern, Txt)>0
)
SELECT STUFF((SELECT ', '+Val FROM Src FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

use the below code and convert in to function

```
declare @str varchar(100)='random text here Task 1234 blah blah more text task 4567 random task 9556'
declare @gstr varchar(100)=''--for saving the output string
declare @flag int=1--to identify the pattern starting
declare @move int=1-- change start of the string 
 while  PATINDEX('%Task%', substring(@str,@move,LEN(@str)))>0
begin
set @str=substring(@str,@move,LEN(@str))
set @flag= PATINDEX('%Task%', @str)
set @gstr= @gstr+','+SUBSTRING(@str, @flag,9)
set @move=@flag+9
end
select STUFF(@gstr,1,1,'')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[f_get_all_patindex](@pat NVARCHAR(256), @str NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        @str AS substr,
        PATINDEX(@pat, @str) AS substr_ix_found, 
        CONVERT(INT, 0) AS index_found
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        SUBSTRING(cte.substr, cte.substr_ix_found + 1, LEN(@str)), 
        PATINDEX(@pat, SUBSTRING(cte.substr, cte.substr_ix_found + 1, LEN(@str))) ,
        CONVERT(INT, cte.index_found + cte.substr_ix_found)
    FROM cte WHERE cte.substr_ix_found > 0
)
SELECT cte.index_found
FROM cte 
WHERE cte.index_found > 0 
GO

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[f_get_all_patindex]('%HH%', '123456HHJ78987HHJ654321qwertyuiopasdfghjklHHHJzxcvbnm')

--the example from the question:

DECLARE @str NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'random text here Task 1234 blah blah more text task 4567'
SELECT index_found, SUBSTRING(@str, index_found, 9) FROM [dbo].[f_get_all_patindex]('%Task%', @str)
```

Could be better performance-wise, and did not made extensive tests, but I prefer than the other solutions because it gives the index just using PATINDEX and SUBSTRING